# How do I start the same docker container on two different ports using docker container?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

Since Products and users use all the same files, just run on different ports, how can I just run the same container twice on two different ports?

```
   version: "3.8"
    services:
     users:
        build: 
            context: './backend'
        ports: 
            - "8081:8081"
        command: node services/auth.js
    
     products:
        build:
            context: './backend'
        ports: 
            - "8080:8080"
        command: node services/products.js

     reactapp: 
        stdin_open: true   
        tty: true
        build: 
            context: './frontend/expense-calculator'
        ports: 
            - "3000:3000"
        command: npm start
```

Comment: The second number in `ports:` needs to match the port number the process inside the container is listening on.  If these are all Express apps listening on port 3000, then you could declare _e.g._ `8080:3000` to map host port 8080 to that container port.  Is there a specific problem or error message you're encountering?

Comment: is this what you want? `docker container port map with host machine's 2 different ports`

Comment: I have 2 express servers, one is products.js other is auth.js and one react app. This file runs all good, but because products and users are initially the same container I don't want to build it twice. So im asking if I can start it twice just with different comands

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this article.
https://medium.com/@karthi.net/how-to-scale-services-using-docker-compose-31d7b83a6648

The idea is simple, use one container and map docker container with the host machine's multiple port numbers. for this, you need to scale the container and tell in docker-compose.yml that my container's port is mapped with host machine's these ports like this.

```
 users:
    build: 
        context: './backend'
    ports: 
        - "8081-8082:8081"
    command: node services/auth.js
```

and docker-compose up command will be:

```
docker-compose -f "docker-composetest.yml" up --scale users=2 -d --build
```

Comment: No sorry, this doesn't help me cause i need to be able to run node services/auth.js
and node services/products.js which are 2 different files and need to run on 2 differents ports

Comment: So you want to run the container or different ports! Hmm. Then why don't you just rename the service names like S1 S2 S3 and change  the ports number also like 8081, 8082 8083 ?

Comment: Just copy and paste the service to multiples as much as you want ! Will that help you?